# How can i have different translations for action controller in TYPO3?

Tags: localization, typo3, realurl

Is it possible to have a localization based on [RealURL](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/realurl)'s `valueMap` static table ?

For example, in *Deutsch* language, I have `www.example.com/de/account/produktinfos/`

1. `de/` is language
2. `account/` page
3. `produktinfos/` controller action

And what I need is to translate the `produktinfos/`part to English, i.e.,  `www.example.com/en/account/productinfo/`.

Is there a way to translate the controller action in RealURL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this help for you.
You can use some realurl post/pre Procs.

for example:

```
// realurl Hook for replacing some path
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array(
  'encodeSpURL_postProc' => array('user_encodeSpURL_postProc'),
  'decodeSpURL_preProc' => array('user_decodeSpURL_preProc')
);
```

and replace controller action in URL

```
function user_encodeSpURL_postProc(&$params, &$ref) {
  $params['URL'] = str_replace('job/job/Job/show/', 'job/', $params['URL']);
}

function user_decodeSpURL_preProc(&$params, &$ref) {
  $params['URL'] = str_replace('job/', 'job/job/Job/show/', $params['URL']);
}
```

the blog post 
https://www.kartolo.de/2014/11/21/extbase-and-realurl/

An other solution can be like that?

```
// news pagebrowser
    'my-action' => array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_myext[action]',
            'valueMap' => array(
                  preg_match('%/de/%',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])==1?'anzeigen':'show' => 'show', 
            )
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: yes, i can use this. But there i couldn't get the sys_language_uid - think that this hooks are triggered more before.

Comment: you can get and check the lang uid with this $GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid ?

Comment: Or you use valueMap in realurl "action" configuration like here http://www.worldhack.de/typo3-extbase-extension-und-realurl/ ?

Comment: Yes, i used like this

Comment: can you configure different localized actions in this value map?

Comment: do you mean to have actions for each language ?

Comment: That's the solution. Thanx !