# RealURL valuemap for different languages?

Tags: typo3, realurl

is there any possibility that I can use different valueMaps for each language in postVarSets?

In the following code I am just able to handle one language:

```
36 => array(    // Main list (pageUid of Typo3)
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_mainlist_aq[controller]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'verwaltung' => 'list'
                ),
                //'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_mainlist_aq[action]',
                'valueMap' => array(
                    'liste' => 'list',
                    'erstellen' => 'new',
                    'erstellt' => 'create',
                    'bearbeiten' => 'edit',
                    'verbinden' => 'connect',
                    'auswertungsliste' => 'show',
                    'aktualisieren' => 'update',
                ),
                //'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Did you check what this guy did here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457500/how-can-i-have-different-translations-for-action-controller-in-typo3